# How to fetch large data from .csv file which contains the first row as header, and show in DataGrid in MAUI (C#) app?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, datagrid, maui

I have a csv file which contains data and first row as headers. I want to get the data in MAUI app and show into a DataGrid. I am able to do this but as the csv contains more than 20K rows, the app is not able to load the data fast and stops responding.

FYI - the search and filter functionality is also included in the app which should work after code optimization.

Please suggest if any solution to fix this problem.

Following is the xaml code for DataGrid in MainPage.xaml

```
 <dg:DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding UserDetails}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
              RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" HeaderBackground="CornflowerBlue" ItemSelected="myDataGrid_ItemSelected" >
     <dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
         <Label Text="Nothing to see here..." HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
     </dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
     <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
         <dg:DataGridColumn Title="EmployeeNo" PropertyName="EmployeeNo" Width="*"/>
         <dg:DataGridColumn Title="FirstName" PropertyName="FirstName" Width="*" />
         <dg:DataGridColumn Title="LastName" PropertyName="LastName" Width="*" />
         <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Location" PropertyName="Location" Width="*" />
         <dg:DataGridColumn Title="CostCenter" PropertyName="CostCenter" Width="*" />
     </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
     <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
         <dg:PaletteCollection>
             <Color>#F2F2F2</Color>
             <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
         </dg:PaletteCollection>
     </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
     <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <!--<conv:StreakToColorConverter x:Key="StreakToColorConverter" />-->
         </ResourceDictionary>
     </dg:DataGrid.Resources>
 </dg:DataGrid>
```

And following is the code to load the data from csv and bind to datagrid (MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
  using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
  {
      parser.SetDelimiters(",");
      bool firstLine = true;
      while (!parser.EndOfData)
      {
          if (firstLine)
          {
              firstLine = false;
              parser.ReadFields();
              continue;
          }
          string[] rows = parser.ReadFields();
          User userDetails = new User();
          userDetails.EmployeeNo = rows[0].ToString();
          userDetails.FirstName = rows[4].ToString();
          userDetails.LastName = rows[3].ToString();
          userDetails.Location = rows[2].ToString();
          userDetails.CostCenter = rows[7].ToString();
          UserDetails.Add(userDetails);
      }
```

This is how the datasouce is mapped on MainPage()

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = UserDetails;
```

Comment: Please give us something to work with. We don't see nor know your code base. So, to make suggestions for improvement, I'd have to make bold assumptions about your code, which may or may not be accurate.

Comment: ^^ That said: 1. Switch from using CSV to a Database. 2. If you can't do that, maybe switch do async I/O and/or read in batches, not in one go. 3. If you are already doing that: show your code, so we can make better suggestions.

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Probably unrelated: You check N times if firstLine is true, and it will be only once. Why not just do one `parser.ReadFields();` _before_ entering the loop?

Comment: This likely has more to do with the UI than CSV file. UI controls for displaying large amount of data often have a "virtualization" feature that allow data to be loaded on demand. Thus only needing as many expensive UI objects as are visible on screen. I would recommend separating the loading part from the UI-parts and do some more measurements.

Comment: Loading a csv file should scale linearly with the file size, and 20k rows might equal ~2Mb? That should not take more than a second or two to load unless you are doing something suboptimal.

Comment: @JonasH - any code suggestions for showing data in Datagrid OnDemand or OnScroll of page?

Comment: @MamtaPatil I have never used MAUI, so no. But both winforms and wpf datagrids have such a feature. So I would expect something equivalent in MAUI. I would recommend looking at the documentation, or third party sources, after things mentioning "virtualization" or "virtual".